# Form submit stops if an error occurs inside function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, fetch

I'm building a user form,
in which I added some `console.log()` statements for fast debugging.
but I noticed that if there's an error inside the `console.log()` E.g: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatted_address' of undefined`,
then the rest of the function stops executing.
Which is weird to me.

Here's the code:

```
function submitted(e) {
  console.log(typeof autocomplete.getPlace());
 console.log("Location: ", autocomplete.getPlace().formatted_address); //this can result in undefined
  const selectedCat = category.options[category.selectedIndex].value;//this can result in undefined if 
                                                                        nothing is selected

//----If any of the above throws an undefined error than the code below won't execute----

  const data = {
    name: bizName,
    email: bizEmail,
    location:
      typeof autocomplete.getPlace() !== "undefined"
        ? autocomplete.getPlace().formatted_address
        : bizAddress,
    owner: {
      firstName: ownerFname,
      lastName: ownerLname,
    },
    phone: phone,
    website: bizUrl,
    category: selectedCat,
    logo: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/picard102/128.jpg",
  };

  console.log(data);

  postData("/business/create", { answer: 42 }).then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    //check for errors from server validation
    if (data.errors) {
      alert(data.errors[0].msg);
    }
  });

  e.preventDefault();

  console.log();
  console.log(e);
}
```

How can I prevent this from happening? Or is something else causing the function to stop running?
Thanks in advance

Comment: That is normal, when javascript hits an error it stops. "*How can I prevent this from happening?*" Fix the error :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten hmmm, that's why I said I'm using it for debugging... lol

Comment: The error in the console is nothing to do with using `console.log` to debug. Whenever javascript encounters an error it will  show the error message in the console, regardless of debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an error will occur then the program execution will stop. if you want to handle the error then use try/catch

The `try` statement allows you to define a block of code to be tested for errors while it is being executed.

The `catch` statement allows you to define a block of code to be executed, if an error occurs in the try block.

The JavaScript statements try and catch come in pairs:

```
try {
  Block of code to try
}
catch(err) {
  Block of code to handle errors
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The values in your `console.log` are being evaluated in that line. If an error is encountered in that line it will error out.

This is by design. It is an unhandled error.

Solution: handle the error.

You can use a try/catch block.

You can also initialize the values before logging them, accessing values only if the object is not undefined...

Comment: "You can also initialize the values before logging them, accessing values only if the object is not undefined..."   how do you do that?

Comment: Say you are accessing `b` from `a`. You expect this data to be available: `a = { b: 'some value' }`. If you try to access `b` but for some reason it is undefined, you will get an error. But if you first check if `a` exists, you can handle it being undefined. `if (a) { // do something with a.b }` `else { // something is wrong! }`